# Can't access Tomcat 7 Manager app when running from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I installed Tomcat 7 from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) and I used the [Windows Service Installer](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

However, none of my old web-apps work, when I create a new web-app and try access it via `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/` it doesn't work unless I append index.jsp...

But, the one thing that bothers me the most is that I can not open the manager app even though I have an admin user defined in conf/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<user name="admin" password="some-pwd" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />
```

The weird thing is that after I installed Tomcat 7 even the manager app in Tomcat 6 would not work anymore.

It simply shows the blank white page with no content, never even asks me for credentials or anything.

Anyone knows what is going on here?

Thanks!

**edit:** It seems that this is a Firefox issue since I was able to access the manager app on Chrome.

However, once I connected Eclipse and started Tomcat from eclipse, the manager app was again broken, even on Chrome. There is an Eclipse issue here. I did copy the ROOT folder from Tomcat to Eclipse [as suggested here](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html) and I even copied the manager folder as well as examples and docs folders.

When I run my test web-app in eclipse, I can see it at `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/` properly. I can also see the Tomcat home page `http://localhost:8080/` properly. But, I can not access the Manager App `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` as it says: "*The requested resource is not available.*"

If I stop Tomcat in Eclipse and start the Windows Service, then I can access the Manager App, but it doesn't show my test web-app in the list.

Comment: This one is for serverfault.com

Comment: never knew about serverfault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with my Firefox installation. After exhausting all options and testing with Chrome, Safari, Opera and even IE, which all worked properly, I decided to uninstall Firefox with removing all profile settings and then re-install it again. **The new installation works.**

*p.s. HINT: if you are uninstalling Firefox completely, don't forget to backup your bookmarks and passwords and save the list of your add-ons ;)
bookmarks can be backed up directly from Firefox
passwords can be stored with an add-on called Password Exporter
add-ons I "save" with a screenshot :D*

Answer (score 0):

I can't find "admin-gui" in appropriate Tomcat docs. Maybe using of this role causes issue?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Comment: Nope. Removed it, restarted Tomcat and it's all the same.
<user name="admin" password="some-pwd" roles="manager-gui" />