# Firefox Tomcat7 Cookie IllegalArgumentException

Tags: eclipse, firefox, cookies, tomcat7

Tomcat 7.0.30
Firefox 15.0.1
Eclipse 3.7 & 4.2

I have recently installed Tomcat7.0.30 and since then I am having all kinds of problems with Firefox. (for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552543/cant-access-tomcat-7-manager-app-when-running-from-eclipse))

Right now I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute.` exception.

I have a plain html file:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>Test htm</body>
</html>
```

This is what Firebug reports:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8080/WSTest"

The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the
transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

What bothers me is that there are no problems whatsoever in chrome. The page just opens as I would expect it to...

I have tried to google this and the only suggestion I found was to add this:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true
```

to the catalina.properties file, but that didn't help.

I'm really loosing my mind here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with my Firefox installation. After exhausting all options and testing with Chrome, Safari, Opera and even IE, which all worked properly, I decided to uninstall Firefox with removing all profile settings and then re-install it again. **The new installation works.**

*p.s. HINT: if you are uninstalling Firefox completely, don't forget to backup your bookmarks and passwords and save the list of your add-ons ;)
bookmarks can be backed up directly from Firefox
passwords can be stored with an add-on called Password Exporter
add-ons I "save" with a screenshot :D*